# How can I shrink large core dumps by removing large data structures?

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

Our process can use 100s of GB of RAM, which obviously creates issues with the size of core dump files. Large files are bad because they take a long time to write, but also (worse for us) they may fill up the partition they are written to.

Further, if the core file is at a remote location, we may want to transfer it over a WAN, and typically that can take in the order of days.

Obviously we can compress the core, and that may reduce the size. What I would like to do is manipulate the core to remove some of the larger data structures from the core files, to slim it down to a more manageable size.

Coming from the inside, we could catch SEGV and write a core dump manually.

Coming from the "outside", we could write some gdb magic to spot where the large structures are, zero them out, and then compress.

Neither approach appeals much...

Comment: Does http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html, Controlling which mappings are written to the core dump help?

Comment: Also see [man ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html).

Comment: @tink, yes controlling mappings may help. Need to check how ancient our kernel is, and then think about using different mappings. That can also be done with http://code.google.com/p/google-coredumper/ which I found in my wanderings.

Comment: @devnull - no ulimit is totally useless, it just truncates, and creates an unusable core. If we didn't want to use the core, we wouldn't produce one at all.

Comment: I would maybe try a different approach: either use something like ABRT, or make core dumps that only hold the stack.  Use this to try to analyze the bug a little bit.  Then use a gdbserver and the tracepoint feature to capture data from a running system to see if useful data can be captured before a failure.  Teaching gdb about the contents of the heap is tricky... it can be done (search for the "gdb-heap" project) but it certainly won't speed up the process of making a core...